# Issue while importing a package residing in another package

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

My directory structure is as follows:

```
package1
| __init__.py
package2
| __init__.py
test.py
```

Right now, I can import package1 and package2 in test.py as follows:
import package1
import package2

## Do stuff

Now I want to change my directory structure as follows:

```
package1
| __init__.py
| package2
| | __init__.py
test.py
```

I want to import this as follows:
from package1 import package2
from package2 import ... (Other functions)

Can this be achieved?

Comment: ```from package1.package2 import ...```

Comment: `from package1 import package2` and use `package2.somefunction(...)` or just do `from package1.package2 import so_and_so_functions`

Comment: For user readability I would like to implement this as:
`from package1 import package2`
`from package2 import package2functions`
And then simply use package2functions directly.